# Using .one() and .on() together - one handler for each element

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="foo" type="button">Click Me</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="foo" type="button">Click Me</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to have a click handler for button.foo only execute once, but I don't want jQuery to remove the handlers from other elements. So when you click the first button, it removes the handler for that button, but not the second button. When you click the second button, it removes the handler for the second button, but not the first button.

Also, when any buttons with the class "foo" are added to the table, I want it to add a click handler that will be removed the first time it is used, and again, not remove other handlers.

```
$("table").one("click", "button.foo", function() {
    // ...
});
```

The above code doesn't work because it removes all handlers the first time any element is clicked. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm asking easily?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind function to DOM events once and only once so that they will not execute for a second time in the triggering of event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951313/how-to-bind-function-to-dom-events-once-and-only-once-so-that-they-will-not-exec) --- just use `.on` instead of `.delegate`. *edit:* I noticed that the question might actually not the same as this one, but the accepted solution would certainly help.

Comment: Instead of calling `one`, do you have the option of changing/removing the class `foo` once a button is clicked?

Comment: Yep its `.off()` or `.removeClass()` depending on if you want to remove the event or class.

Comment: This is a better duplicate: [is there a way to force event to fire only once on given element (per element, not whole document) when using live()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201242/is-there-a-way-to-force-event-to-fire-only-once-on-given-element-per-element-n) -- again, assume `.on` instead of `.live`, the idea stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the class after the `click` event.

```
$("table").on("click", "button.foo", function() {
    alert("click!");
    $(this).removeClass("foo");
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mhusaini/dGKsj/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("table button.foo").one("click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to use event delegation, that's why he cannot use `.one`.